# How to get GE Lo-Water PreciseFill unstuck from rinse mode?

Tags: washing-machine

The washer fills. Then "rinses". Then fills. Then rinses. Over and over again, skipping all cycles, never making it to spin/finish. It spins, but the indicator light always says rinse.

It never stops. It doesn't agitate, the light never turn on for "soak" or "wash".

Is it the timer? It moves. And the modes seem to be firmware controlled.

kewords: stuck in spin mode, stuck on spin. Perpetual spin mode. stuck in rinse cycle. will only spin, will only rinse.

Comment: My best guess is that it is the timer. It can fill with water and it spina and it drains, so it's not the pump, the pump filter or the belt or anything. I ordered a new timer and it just got here. I'll post the update to see if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a bad timer. Since it drained, and spun and rinsed, I knew it was not the pump or filter or motor. I found "the last one" online, but it was a super easy fix that saved my hundreds of dollars (thousands if my girlfriend had her way). Just locate your model number (on the inside of the lid, or under it on the body).

Just pop the top control panel off by removing three screws. Then unscrew the circuit board. The handles just pull off with evenly applied pressure.

[image]
[image]